# Replacing special characters in files in the fastest way possible?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode-string

I have some files which contain special characters like `é,ã,Δ,Ù` etc. I want to replace them to their NCR (hex) 4 digit values. I've tried the below method of doing so but not sure whether it is the fastest possible way of achieving my goal...

```
var entities = new[]
{
new { ser = "\u00E9", rep = @"&#x00E9;" },
new { ser = "\u00E3", rep = @"&#x00E3;" },
new { ser = "\u00EA", rep = @"&#x00EA;" },
new { ser = "\u00E1", rep = @"&#x00E1;" },
new { ser = "\u00C1", rep = @"&#x00C1;" },
new { ser = "\u00C9", rep = @"&#x00C9;" },
new { ser = "\u0394", rep = @"&#x0394;" },
new { ser = "\u03B1", rep = @"&#x03B1;" },
new { ser = "\u03B2", rep = @"&#x03B2;" },
new { ser = "\u00B1", rep = @"&#x00B1;" },
//... so on
};

var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string txt = File.ReadAllText(file);

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(txt, entity.ser))
        {
            txt = Regex.Replace(txt, entity.ser, entity.rep);
        }
    };
    File.WriteAllText(file, txt);
}
```

Is there a faster way and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you check if there is a match first?

Comment: @john Not all files have all the characters in them..thats why and the anonymous type will have few hundreds of `ser` and `rep` in them

Comment: And why do you need a regular expression for that? c# is not Javascript, and regular expressions might actually be slower then a simple string.replace. Also, since you are potentially doing a lot of replacement, you might want to use a StringBuilder instead of a string.

Comment: @ZoharPeled How do I search for the special characters in a simple string.replace?

Comment: So what? replace will just do nothing if there is nothing to replace. in fact, if memory serves, it actually contains that condition in it's implementation, so there's no point of doing the same condition twice.

Comment: You don't need to search, just run the replace. It will do the search internally.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing - However slow the c# code gets, it's negligible comparing to the time your code spends on I/O (opening and saving the files). so optimizing the replace method is not going to give you any clear benefit.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Are you saying to use `txt= txt.Replace(entity.ser, entity.rep);` instead of `txt = Regex.Replace(txt, entity.ser, entity.rep);`?  I thought strings like `"\u00B1", "\u03B2"`, require regex search to find

Comment: I'm saying it might be faster. those "strings" are in fact unicode chars string representations. Now that you've asked, I'm not sure how `string.Replace` will treat them. I'm also not saying it is faster, just saying it **might be** faster. Anyway, the I/O is the real time consumer here, as I wrote in my previous comment. I don't think you can do any major improvement to the c# code given that limitation.

Comment: It looks like you are replacing unicode with html representation (see wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).  You can use  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) and  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: @TheGeneral about 1MB

Comment: Is it enough to just replace '\u' with '&#x'? If so, a single Regex.Replace would do the trick: `Regex.Replace(txt, @"\\u", "&#x")`

Comment: @ryans it is not enough to just replace '\u' with '&#x' bcoz the file contains the characters like '' Ù'' and not their hex values

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Let me post something shortly and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Did you read my comment about using htmlEncode?

Comment: @jdweng using `string encodedString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Text);` converts the entities to 3 digit codes like `&#233`...thats not what I want, I want 4 digit hex codes only

Comment: It is a 3 digit decimal number 0 to 255 so four places do not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @jdweng Er, you can't code a 16 bit value in 3 decimal digits.

Comment: Look at the wiki page I referenced.  The 0x0394 should be in html &Delta; and will be properly replaced using htmlEncode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you want to replace the unicode characters (eg Ù) with their Unicode value (&#x00D9). A Regex.Replace will likely be the best way to achieve this.

Here is the loop for processing the files:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string txt = File.ReadAllText(file);

    string newTxt = Regex.Replace(
        txt,
        @"([^\u0000-\u007F]+)",
        HandleMatch);

    File.WriteAllText(file, newTxt);
}
```

And here is the match evaluator:

```
private static char[] replacements = new[]
{
    'ø',
    'Ù'
};

private static string HandleMatch(Match m)
{
    // The pattern for the Regex will only match a single character, so get that character
    char c = m.Value[0];

    // Check if this is one of the characters we want to replace
    if (!replacements.Contains(c))
    {
        return m.Value;
    }

    // Convert the character to the 4 hex digit code
    string code = ((int) c).ToString("X4");

    // Format and return the code
    return "&#x" + code;
}
```

In the loop, you only need to read in the file once, then the Regex.Replace method will handle the replacement of all instances in the input. The pattern for the regex will match everything that is not in the range of 0x00 - 0x7f, which will be the first 255 characters (ASCII characters).

If you need to only replace specific Unicode characters, you will need to build a list of these characters, and check the value of 'c' in the `HandleMatch()` function against that list.

**Comments on performance:**
You are trying to perform selective character replacement on a set of files. At a minimum, you are going to have to read each file into memory, then examine each character to see if it meets you criteria.

A more performant option *could* be to build a lookup table of characters, then the replacement strings for each. The trade-off there would be that if you had a large list of chars that needed replacing, the table would quickly being unwieldy to maintain. You also leave the open the risk of errors in the replacement table, which would be more work to find.

Comment: **"If you need to only replace specific Unicode characters, you will need to build a list of these characters"**   can you show how? BTW, this process does look more time consuming though?

Comment: Updated the code. Also, if you need to replace **most but not all** characters, you could easily turn the list into a negative list by removing the `!` from the check.